# Category on y axis using syncfusion chart JS1

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

I'm using syncfusion JS1 in my project and I'm constructing a syncfusion chart using javascript. I couldn't find any way to have string on the y-axis.

I want to plot multiple state of the hardware over time. the states are "Auto", "Charge", "Discharge"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greetings from Syncfusion. We have analyzed your requirement. As of now, category axis (string values) support is given only for x axis and not for y axis. Hence kindly revert us with more information of the exact requirement, if possible kindly share some screenshots, so that we can analyze and provide you the solution at earlier.

Meanwhile, we have prepared a chart using the bar series and the sample can be find [here](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/jydv2ecv). For more information chart types, kindly find the [user guide](https://help.syncfusion.com/js/chart/chart-types). You can also find the online demo sample for [category axis](https://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/chart/column).

Screenshot:
[image: Bar Series]

Thanks, Dharani.